Problem when code is inside module
I have this code:
PolynomialToFallingFactorial[f_] := Module[{terms, convertedTerms,fallingFactorialForm, FFcoeff, result},
  (* Extract terms of the polynomial f *)
  terms = List @@ Expand[f];
  Print["terms",terms];
  (* Replace each monomial x^n with its falling factorial representation *)
  convertedTerms =replaceList[terms, x];
  Print["cterms",convertedTerms];
  (* Sum up the converted terms *)
fallingFactorialForm = Total[convertedTerms]

FFcoeff = Cases[fallingFactorialForm, t :(Times[coef_Integer, __] | Times[coef_Plus, __]) :> If[IntegerQ[coef], coef, 1], {1}]

FFcoeff = Table[FFcoeff[[i]] / (i+1), {i, Length[FFcoeff]}]

result = FallingFactorial[x, Range[1, Length[FFcoeff]]+1] . FFcoeff
result
]

The problem starts at the part where FFcoeff is defined. If I cut this part until result into the main notebook the code works perfectly, however once I copy it into the module I only get something like result$79117 {}.FFcoeff$79117 .
This is probably a beginner question but I wasn't able to solve it.

Should replaceList be ReplaceList? I can't be sure without example test data

Undefined functions and variables: ctermsreplaceList, coef, FallingFactorial
